# Print Dynamic variable inside DynamicModule

Tags: dynamic, wolfram-mathematica

Why is it that not the value of *b* gets **printed** in the following example but the symbolname? How can I force the printing of the actual dynamic value of the variable?

```
a = {1, 2, 3};

DynamicModule[{b},
 Print[Dynamic[b]];
 {Dynamic[a], Dynamic[b]}
 ,
 Initialization :> (b = Length[a]; a = a + 2)
 ]
```

output:

```
b$107

Out[2]= {{3, 4, 5}, 3}
```

**Edit** (after reading your answers/comments):

Consider the more simple example, without `Initialization` code (to get around WReach's example):

```
a = {1, 2, 3};

DynamicModule[{b = Length[a]},
 Print[Dynamic[b]];
 {Dynamic[a], Dynamic[b]}
 ]
```

output:

```
During evaluation of In[4]:= b$602

Out[5]= {{1, 2, 3}, 3}
```

Note, that this example does what I want to if I use `Module` instead of `DynamicModule` or leave out `Dynamic` from the `Print` line. My concerns are:

1. Why does this second example fail to print the value of *b* correctly? There is no Initialization, which (according to the help) contains "an expression to evaluate when the DynamicModule is first displayed". Also according to help: "When `DynamicModule` is first evaluated, initial assignments for local variables are made first, and then any setting for the `Initialization` option is evaluated."
2. The help should read: "Initialization: an expression to evaluate when the **result of** `DynamicModule` is first displayed", meaning that a `Print` statement onscreen does not constitute the "result" of the `DynamicModule`. If this is correct, then (and only then) I understand why the `Print` statement does not mean that the `Dynamic` object appears correctly.

Comment: Please see my updated, updated reply.

Comment: Is there part of your question that remains unanswered?

Comment: @Wizard: I will evaluate this issue some other time, unfortunately I'm a bit busy now, sorry. I'm working at tectonic speeds...

Comment: It was hard to decide between Mr.Wizard's and WReach's answers, but I felt that the latter one explained the phenomena in a way that I could understand better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crucial behaviour is described under the *More Information* section of the documentation for [DynamicModule](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DynamicModule.html):

> *DynamicModule* first gives unique names to local variables in *expr*,
>   just like *Module*, then evaluates the resulting expression, and then
>   returns a version of this wrapped in *DynamicModule*.

The exact sequence of events becomes more apparent if you add a `Print` statement to the `Initialization` option, thus:

```
a = {1, 2, 3};

DynamicModule[{b},
 Print[Dynamic[b]];
 {Dynamic[a], Dynamic[b]}
 ,
 Initialization :> (b = Length[a]; Print["init:", b]; a = a + 2)
 ]
```

resulting in three cells:

```
        b$107

Out[7]= {{3, 4, 5}, 3}

        init:3
```

The cell containing `b$107` is the result of the `Print` inside the `DynamicModule`.  Then, we get the result cell (tagged `Out[7]` here).  Finally, we see the third cell output by `Print` statement in the `Initialization`.

If you inspect the cell expression of the `Out[7]` cell, you will find that the localized variable is `b$$`.  This is different from the variable in the first cell, which is `b$107`.  This difference is attributable to the "double scoping" described in the `DynamicModule` documentation.  The `b$107` cell contains a `Dynamic` box, as can be seen if we assign a value to `b$107`.

**Update**

In response to the updated question...

Returning to the original expression (without the extra `Print` in the `Initialization`), the exact sequence of events is as follows:

First, the body of the `DynamicModule` is evaluated after giving "unique names to local variables [...] just like *Module*".  That is, this expression is evaluated:

```
Print[Dynamic[b$107]]; {Dynamic[a], Dynamic[b$107]}
```

The result of this expression is the list `{Dynamic[a], Dynamic[b$107]}`.  As a side-effect, a dynamic cell containing `b$107` is created but that cell is now removed from further consideration as it is not part of the result of the evaluation.  Now, "a version of [`{Dynamic[a], Dynamic[b$107]}`] is wrapped in *DynamicModule*" and returned.  This is evaluated and implicitly printed to produce an output cell expression like this:

```
Cell[BoxData[
 DynamicModuleBox[{$CellContext`b$$ = 3}, 
  RowBox[{"{", 
   RowBox[{
    DynamicBox[ToBoxes[$CellContext`a, StandardForm],
     ImageSizeCache->{57., {2., 8.}}], ",", 
    DynamicBox[ToBoxes[$CellContext`b$$, StandardForm],
     ImageSizeCache->{7., {0., 8.}}]}], "}"}],
  DynamicModuleValues:>{},
  Initialization:>($CellContext`b$$ = 
    Length[$CellContext`a]; $CellContext`a = $CellContext`a + 2)]], "Output"]
```

Note particularly that `b$107` is renamed to `` $CellContext`b$$ `` as a function of `DynamicModule` symbol localization.  The `Initialization` expression is now evaluated as the box is displayed and visible.

The key point is that the printed cell containing `b$107` is not coupled in any way to the final `DynamicModule` cell.

Comment: I think this only partially answers my question, see edit in original post.

Comment: See the new section, *Update*.

Answer (score 7):

I believe this happens because the `Dynamic` object `b` has not been displayed at the time the `Print` statement is called, and therefore the initialization has not been made.  As I recall, `Dynamic` functionality does not operate until it is actually, visibly displayed.

See [Why won't this work? Dynamic in a Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179430/why-wont-this-work-dynamic-in-a-select/1581155#1581155) for more information.

---

In response to your update, my theory is that the `Dynamic` statement within `Print` in never displayed by the FrontEnd, and therefore it is never actually initialized.  That is, it remains a unique placeholder, waiting to be filled by the dynamic value of `b` when it is finally displayed.

One may see from the example below that the assignment RHS evaluation takes place before the body `Print`, at least by measure of the display order in the FrontEnd.  Further, we see that `Print` "goes inside" `Dynamic` and takes the unique symbol name created by `DynamicModule`, and prints that.  We can use `ToString` to cause `Print` to display the entire expression as it is.  Likewise, if we extract the symbol name from that string, and convert it to an actual symbol, before printing, we get the expected value that has indeed already been assigned.

```
alarm := (Print["Initialized!"]; 3)

DynamicModule[{b = alarm},
  Print @ ToString @ Dynamic @ b;
  Print @ Symbol @ StringTake[ToString@Dynamic@b, {9, -2}];
  Print @ Dynamic @ b;
];
```

Output:

```
Initialized!

Dynamic[b$701]

3

b$701
```

Comment: @belisarius I think it does, because as you may observe, the `Print` line appears before the output line, therefore the `Dynamic` object *still* has not been initialized at the time of printing.

Comment: My Dynamic-fu is pretty weak ... Why is Print[] evaluated before the {...} ?

Comment: @belisarius at risk of being rude, did you read John Fultz' explanation?  `Dynamic` is a weird function, and I assume it relies on the FrontEnd, while I expect the actual call of the `Print` function is handled by the kernel.

Comment: OMG. Sorry, didn't see that! Deleting all my comments until I finish reading. Tnx!

Comment: @belisarius It's too late, I've read them and will tell the others :)

Comment: What a shame! Now I will have to wear sunglasses here.

Comment: @belisarius, that won't help your reading ability. (I'm sorry, I couldn't resist.)

Comment: Ok. I understood now. Dynamic works only when you have your sunglasses on, while Print works when you open your sunglasses's case.