# Mathematica Dynamic List Manipulation

Tags: dynamic, wolfram-mathematica

I am stuck on what I think should be a relatively simple concept.  I am not understanding how Dynamic[] functions with regarding incremental list manipulations.  Consider the following statements:

```
In[459]:= x={{1,2}};
In[462]:= y=First[x]
Out[462]= {1,2}
In[463]:= z=First[y]
Out[463]= 1
```

Simple right?  Now, I want z to dynamically update when I change x.  Here is my attempt:

```
In[458]:= a={{1,2}};
In[452]:= b=Dynamic[First[a]]
Out[452]= {1,2}
In[449]:= c=Dynamic[First[b]]
Out[449]= {1,2}
```

As I change the values in list a, I see corresponding change is b and c; however, I would expect each statement to **Part** the first element.  Manipulations on Dynamic lists are not taking.

My question is why do we see this behavior, and how can I apply consecutive Dynamic list manipulations?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dynamic works in an unusual way.  See: [Why won't this work? Dynamic in a Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179430/why-wont-this-work-dynamic-in-a-select/1581155#1581155)

The assignment `b = Dynamic[First[a]]` does not evaluate to anything other than the literal expression `Dynamic[First[a]]` until that expression is to be visibly displayed on screen.

Therefore when you write `First[b]` you are asking for the first part of `Dynamic[First[a]]` which is `First[a]`.

The fact that `Dynamic` is in a way more of a display trick than an internal functionality should not be overlooked lightly.  Mistaking the function of `Dynamic` will lead to much confusion and frustration.  Nevertheless, in your simple example you can get the behavior you want, at least visually, with this:

```
b = Dynamic[First[a]]

c = Dynamic[First@First[b]]
```

Comment: @Heike I thought I was just picking up scraps.  I didn't know you were still answering questions over here. :-)

Comment: I check in occasionally when it's quiet on mma.SE

Answer (score 2):

You've already gotten an answer why `Dynamic` doesn't work as you expected, but I'll add how to achieve what (I think) you want:

```
a={{1,2}}
(*
==> {{1,2}}
*)

b:=First[a];Dynamic[b]
(*
==> {1,2}
*)

c:=First[b];Dynamic[c]
(*
==> 1
*)

a={{3,4}}
(*
==> {{3,4}}
-- The displays for b and c now change to {3,4} and 3
*)
```

By using `SetDelayed` (`:=`) you make sure that every time `b` and `c` are evaluated, the current value of `a` is used, rather than the value it had at the point of definition. And the `Dynamic` makes sure that the displayed value is re-evaluated whenever `a` is changed.